# What characters are used as wildcards in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm a Stata user who is learning SAS. What characters are used as wildcards in SAS? In Stata it is the asterisk. I read that in SAS you can use `:` as a wildcard for suffixes, but I need the same for prefixes. Does that exist?

For example, if I am trying to find any variable in my data set that includes the string "findme", in Stata I would do

`list *findme*`

to specify that the variable could have numbers or characters either before or after the string "findme".

What is the SAS equivalent? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for the variable name or a value contained in the variable?

Comment: This question is framed as if I'm looking for any variable name with the string "findme" in it. But the question is nonspecific: I am asking what characters are used as wildcards in SAS whether I am looking for a variable name, a value, or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

One way of finding a list of column names in SAS with a common substring is to query the metadata tables, e.g.

```
data work.example;
length findme1 _findme _findme_ anothervar 8;
output;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select name into :var_list 
    separated by ' ' 
    from dictionary.columns 
    where libname='WORK' 
      and memname ='EXAMPLE'
      and lowcase(name) like '%findme%'
      ;
quit;

%put &VAR_LIST;
```

There is no single wildcard character that works for prefixes in the way that `:` does for suffixes. If all your common-suffix variables form a contiguous list in the column order of your dataset, however, you can use a double-dash list like so:

```
data work.example;
length b_findme c_findme a_findme anothervar 8;
output;
run;

data example_subset;
  set example (keep = b_findme--a_findme);
run;
```

If you want more powerful wildcard and pattern matching for variable names, your best bet is to go back to `proc sql` as per the other part of my answer and use `prxmatch('/your_regex_here/', name)` as part of your where clause rather than `like`. Then you can use [regular expressions](https://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf) to select your variables.

Comment: Thank you for answering the scenario I gave as an example. However, I am trying to find out what characters are used as wildcards in SAS whether I am looking for a variable name, a value, or anything else. From looking at your answer, does the underscore or percent sign do that? Or no?

Comment: The `SQL` wildcards for the `LIKE` operator are percent `%` (any number of any char) and underscore `_` (one any char)